# error when type 'sudo npm install -g meteorite'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

I'm trying to install the meteorite. I've success to install nodejs(v0.10.7).and when I type 'sudo npm install -g meteorite'. It comes the error below. I think it may exist some problem with npm(1.2.21). But I do not how to solve it. And I use ubuntu12.10 64bit. Any ideas?

> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite

> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite

> npm ERR! Error: ENOTDIR, mkdir '/home/icarus/tmp/npm-5885/1369411459617-0.27502001402899623'

> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:

> npm ERR! or email it to:

> npm ERR!     npm-@googlegroups.com

> npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic

> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "meteorite"

> npm ERR! cwd /home/icarus

> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7

> npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.21

> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452791/npm-install-error-enotdir

Comment: I follow this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452791/npm-install-error-enotdir)provided by @tymeJV. And I follow the way that type 'rm ~/tmp' to remove the file. Then I install meteorite again. It works! Thinks a lot.

Comment: guys, post an answer @tymeJV or mark it as duplicate. Thanks

Comment: oh, sorry. I am new here. I have marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

For those who landed here first like me, this is usually an issue with a tmp folder in your root directory followed by npm trying to install from the cache.  This should fix it:

```
rm -rf ~/tmp
sudo npm cache clear
sudo npm install -g meteorite
```

If you still get the ENOTDIR error you can try making the directory yourself, clearing the cache, and reinstalling, but it looks like removing the tmp folder usually does the trick.

Props to [Coombesy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288644/coombesy) for posting this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452791/npm-install-error-enotdir).

Comment: It is NOT recommended to use `sudo npm` --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290986/how-to-fix-eacces-issues-with-npm-install/29787931#29787931