# Bower component download failures in CodeKit

Tags: bower, codekit

I downloaded the latest version of CodeKit (trial version 2.0 (16828)). It starts fine on my Mac Mini, but as soon as I try to download a component using Bower, it fails with the error: "Bower Error / Bower could not determine which components are installed in this project. Make sure you're connected to the Internet and try again." Repeated attempts (either clicking "Retry" or clicking "OK" and trying to download the component again) continue to fail.

[image: Bower Error dialog]

The app completes the "Downloading Bower component list" without error. The error occurs when it is "Scanning For Installed Components..."

I'm connected to the Internet just fine.

When I try to install a Bower component, it fails with this message:

[image: Bower Result error 2]

Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix CodeKit?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Bower installed on your system at the command line? Have you modified your Git installation in any way? (I'm the guy that wrote CodeKit)

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble; we'll get it working.

Comment: Bower was installed (using npm) but broken. I removed it. Git is installed and working fine via the command line. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Chiming in as well with same issue. Just upgraded from 1.9 > 2. Cannot install Foundation or bower items (jquery etc). Using Tower for GIT.

Comment: Whatever is causing Bower to break on the command line is likely the same thing causing it to break inside CodeKit. Something is misconfigured on your machine. One guy solved this by updating Git to the latest version. Try that, or try using this special build of the app --> http://incident57.com/codekit/files/codekit-gitfix.zip

Comment: Am now getting this error - "CodeKit was able to clone Foundation's Git repository to your project folder, but it could not download the latest components using Bower" - Updated GIT via uninstall.sh and re-install with 1.8.4.2

Comment: Not sure who down-voted this, but I canceled them out with an up-vote. Sometimes I really despise Stack Overflow -- if you don't have anything positive to contribute, just move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Bower continued to fail, which prevented CodeKit from working.

[Tolga Akyuz's answer to Siddharth's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452791/npm-install-error-enotdir) was the fix - I had a ~/.cache file which was preventing Bower from adding files to ~/.cache/

When I renamed the ~/.cache file (e.g. to ~/.cache-orig) and created a ~/.cache/ directory, Bower began working properly - and so did CodeKit.

Comment: Similar problem reported in [the npm repository on github - issue 3594](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3594)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this behavior can be caused by several things. Another user fixed it and shared this with me:

I installed xcode and still had issues. After a bit of research, I found a post that said installing the command line tools in Xcode might solve the problem. I did that and the problem is now solved.

From what I can see, there is a appears to be an issue with the $PATH getting messed up with systems that have been upgraded from Lion (and Snow Leopard) that did not ship with git. In the questions and answers listed on the page linked below, there were several terminal command options given, but I was unsure of which to choose so I went with the Xcode route.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/why-is-git-not-found-after-installing-os-x-lion

Comment: ^ This - installing command lines tools worked for me - everything else suggested - not at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

1. Check console messages (mac)
2. Delete faulty library. I had one.
3. Should be all good now.

good luck

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on your answer? I'm having the same problem and none of the fixes I've found seem to be fixing this. I've been without Codekit assets for weeks :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant. In my case it was Google Maps AMD Loader Plugin. All fixed after removing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with path to the project folder – it contains "!" symbol that makes bower crazy. To check is it Bower or CodeKit problem try to cd in terminal to your project folder and run "bower list".

zhaba$ bower list
bower EINVALID      Name must be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes, "@" or spaces

With corrected project folder path CodeKit works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd recommend to format the parts which are code as code (either by indentation or with backticks). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running CodeKit2 with El Capitan, and an old version of Xcode. Updating Xcode fixed the problem.