# Getting npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory while installing package which depends on another

Tags: node.js, npm

Note: I have latest npm and node versions. I have tried the answers provided in [npm install error ENOTDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452791/npm-install-error-enotdir) but didn't work for me.

I need to install 2 npm modules got as .tgz packages on NodeRed

```
1. x.tgz
2. y.tgz
```

I could install the first package using `npm install path/to/x.tgz`

I used the same command `npm install path/to/y.tgz` command but I am getting following error.

```
malintha@malintha-VirtualBox:~/.node-red$ sudo npm install path/to/y.tgz 

npm ERR! path path/to/y.tgz/x.tgz

npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat 'path/to/y.tgz/x.tgz'
```

According to the error log, y module is looking for x.tgz inside it. Then I checked the `package.json` of `y.tgz` artefact.

I can see it has `x.tgz` as the dependency inside it, but it don't have x.tgz inside it.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@abc/pqr": "file:x.tgz",
    "ajv": "^6.5.1",
    "debug": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

According to the instructions, it should be fine if I install the x.tgz and then y.tgz. I could install these `x` and `y` some time back but now I cannot install it.

What might be the root cause for this issue?
Is this npm and node versions related issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm re-writing this answer after deleting my old answer. I tested it with and node v11.6.0 and npm v4.5.0-next.0 on Linux.

To install y.tgz, I tried as below:

1. I copied both tgz files in the same directory.
2. I modified `package.json` of y.tgz as below:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "@abc/pqr": "file:../x.tgz",
       "ajv": "^6.5.1",
       "debug": "^3.1.0"
   }
   ```

`dependencies` supports `file:` + relative path or absolute path.

So, you can choose anyone as your development condition.

Comment: Copying both tgz files into the same directory, to where I am installing those solved the issue.